# Is there a faster way to find a file than by listing all files in the directory?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, filesystems

I've got a workflow that looks like this:

```
for i in some_list:
    if i not in os.listdir(a_directory):
        x = do_something(i)
        x.to_pickle(f"{a_directory}/{i}")
```

The `os.listdir` is expensive, because the directory is huge, and because it's over a network file system.

I have multiple workers doing this job, so I can't just list the contents of the directory once.  If I do, then my workers will duplicate their work, and `do_something` is more expensive after all than `os.listdir`.

Is there something that looks for the presence of a specific file, rather than dumping all of them into a python list for me to string match on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly check to see if a file exists, per this question: [Check whether a file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-without-exceptions)

From that answer:

```py
import os.path
os.path.isfile(fname)
```

Or:

```py
from pathlib import Path

my_file = Path("/path/to/file")
if my_file.is_file():
    # file exists
```